# How can I have instances of Base and Sub-Classes in one List?

Tags: java, generics

I'm currently facing an issue with base and subclasses.

While having a single object as parameter (method  single)  the compiler doesn't complain.

But if it comes to lists the compiler forces me to declare the list as `<? extends Base>`

After that I'm no longer allowed to add objects of the base type to that list.

How can I use both types (Base and Subclass) in one list?

```
public class Generics {

    class Base {    }

    class Sub extends Base{     }

    interface I {
        public void list( List<Sub> list );
        public void single( Sub p);
    }

    class C implements I {
        public void list( List<Sub> list) {     }
        public void single( Sub p) {        }
    }

    void test() {
        C c = new C();
        c.single( new Sub() );
        c.list( new ArrayList<Base>() ); // The method list(List<Generics.Sub>) in the type Generics.C is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Generics.Base>)

    }

    public static void main( String[] args) {
        Generics g = new Generics();
        g.test();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
public void list(List<Sub> list);
```

to:

```
public void list(List<? extends Base> list);
```

Using just `List<Base>` will give you compiler errors like this one:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Sub> subs = new ArrayList<Sub>();
    doSomethingWith(subs); // The method doSomethingWith(List<Base>) in the type Main is not applicable for the arguments (List<Sub>)
}

private static void doSomethingWith(List<Base> bases) {
    // Do something with bases
}
```

If all you're going to pass is `List<Base>` to `doSomethingWith`, then this point is moot, since this won't give you a compiler error. If you want to pass lists that are of a specific type (such as `List<Sub>` above), then you need to change `doSomethingWith` to:

```
private static void doSomethingWith(List<? extends Base> bases) {
```

This fixes the problem. You could also do it at the caller lever (but it's a bit messier):

```
    List<Sub> subs = new ArrayList<Sub>();
    doSomethingWith(new ArrayList<Base>(subs));
```

One issue with the wildcard (`?`) approach is that you can't add new items to the list. To do that, you need something like:

```
private static <B extends Base> void doSomethingWith(List<B> bases) {
```

And then add only `B` instances to `bases`.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare all your lists as

```
List<Base> list;
```

Then you can add both `Base` objects and objects of any subclass.

Comment: @stacker: No, that's why I advised you to declare _all_ lists as `List<Base>`.

Answer (score 1):

Below are the 2 ways to do it....

```
public void inTake(List<? extends Base> list){

}
```

**Or**

```
public T extends Base void inTake(List<T> list){

}
```

Comment: In this case you can't add Lists of type Base

Comment: @stacker in the above answer both of the statements means Anything which extends Base, ie IS-A relationship. Dog IS-A Animal, but its very important to note that Animal is itself an Animal

Comment: sorry all this must have been a problem with my environment, now it works.(+1)