# How does Subclassing for Lists work?

Tags: java, generics

I asked a similiar question 10 minutes ago, but pasted the wrong code snippet. I'm really sorry about that.

I'm currently facing an issue with base and subclasses.

While having a single object as parameter (method single) the compiler doesn't complain.

But if it comes to lists the compiler forces me to declare the list as `<? extends Base>`

After that I'm no longer allowed to add objects of the base type to that list.

The error message: "The method list(List<Generics.Base>) in the type Generics.C is not applicable for the arguments (List<Generics.Sub>)"

```
public class Generics {

    class Base {    }

    class Sub extends Base{     }

    interface I {
        public void list( List<Base> list );
        public void single( Base list );
    }

    class C implements I {
        public void list( List<Base> b) {       }
        public void single( Base p) {       }
    }

    void test() {
        C c = new C();
        c.single( new Sub() );
        List<Sub> b = new ArrayList<Sub>(); 
        c.list( b );                    // error message as above
    }

    public static void main( String[] args) {
        Generics g = new Generics();
        g.test();
    }
}
```

Is there any other way but declaring the list-methods argument as type  `<? extends Base>` ?

Comment: If you made a mistake in the previous question, why couldn't you edit and correct it? That question had quite a few answers that have been left hanging.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn Changing the questin in place would have changed the context and correct answers would possibly downvoted.

Comment: You make an interesting point. I'll look and see what Meta.SO has to say. In that previous question you still could have left the question's content there so the answers had a context and could continue to be up-voted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Below are the 2 ways to do it....**

```
public void list(List<? extends Base> list){

}
```

Or

```
public <T extends Base> void list(List<T> list){

}
```

Comment: As per [my answer to his previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12568937/646634), ofc :P

Comment: @Brian It seems we are destined to meet more than once today.... once again nice meeting you at this wonderful journey called stackoverflow.....